# Developing efficient complex queries with multiple includes in Rails 4

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I may be way off base here, but my general understanding of relational databases is that having information broken into tables makes for faster querying.  So, I designed a somewhat complicated data structure.  I had no trouble implementing it with migrations, and model relations (has_many, belongs_to, etc).  I thought that is would allow for easy querying - but I seem to be missing something!  I have spent the better part of a week trying to build some sort of query (or multiples), but I'm getting nowhere.

I need bits and pieces of about 5 tables for my output.  Additionally, I need to find unique entries on a combination of 3 fields (think first, middle, and last name where last name is from another table).  To further complicate things I need to find arrays of objects (think pens owned by each person).

Rather than get bogged down with the specifics of the code, I was wondering if people might recommend some good videos or blogs that might help me understand what I'm doing.  I've tried to wade my way through RailsGuides, and a few of the doc sites, but my understanding is spotty, and I'm having a hard time pulling it all together.

I also think that starting off this way, might show me that I've made conceptual and design errors that might not be apparent if I were to just post 100's of line of code.

Comment: This is a difficult question to answer. Here's a starting point: http://www.datanamic.com/support/lt-dez005-introduction-db-modeling.html

Comment: @sean - thanks, this looks like an incredible helpful resource.  I realize there probably isn't one entry that will "solve" this issue.  Is there any info that I can add that would help?